# "SystemError: failed to call gpg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" while trying to install driver for Epson WP-4530 printer

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, epson

I am trying to install the driver for my Epson WP-4530 printer.  I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My printer is connected to my home network router.  The printer install utility is able to detect the printer and find the driver for it.  It recommends to install the Epson Inkjet printer driver for Linux (Version 1.0.2).  However, when I select the driver and click the activate button, I receive the following error:

```
SystemError: failed to call gpg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

There is no help feature, I don't know what this error means, and I haven't found any useful help using search engines.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I needed to download the driver from Epson.  I downloaded the correct driver and installed it using the Ubuntu Software Centre. Everything worked fine.